# Is calling SmtpClient(host,0) equivalent to calling SmtpClient(host)

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

We're developing an application which uses SMTP; the host is configured in our DB and we want allow an optional port to be specified (so that SSL can be used in future).

Easiest seems to be to set `port==0` when reading from the DB but I need to confirm that .NET will treat this exactly the same as not specifying a port at all?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w4as51(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`SmtpClient(string, int)` constructor documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w4as51(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If port is zero, Port is initialized using the settings in the application or machine configuration files.

As you can see from the [`SmtpNetworkElement` configuration element documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.smtpnetworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx), this defaults to port 25, exactly the same as when you call the contructor with only a `host` parameter.

If you don't want that, it's as simple as:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient;

if (yourConfiguration.SmtpPort.HasValue)
{
    smtpClient = new SmtpClient(yourConfiguration.SmtpHost, yourConfiguration.SmtpPort.Value);
}
else
{
    smtpClient = new SmtpClient(yourConfiguration.SmtpHost);
}
```

Comment: I read the documentation but it didn't answer my question. That's _why_ I linked to the documentation to show I'd read it. I don't know what those configuration files do. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?cb=1

Comment: You don't link to the documentation, and the documentation states _"For more information about using the application and machine configuration files, see [`<mailSettings>` Element (Network Settings)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx)"_.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this sets my mind at rest. I'd meant to add the link but somehow it didn't make it through (copied and forgot to paste!)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to confirm is in this [link (SmtpClient source code)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs) (line 160)

```
if(port == 0)
  port = defaultPort;//25
```

Comment: Source is subject to change. Documentation is supposed to hold the truth.